# How to Convert a PSD Drop Shadow To Svg?

Tags: svg, photoshop

I have a PSD - Containing Ellipse with a drop shadow for example:

- Mode: Multiply
- Opacity: 15%
- Angle: 120
- Use Global Light On
- Distance: 3px
- Spread: 0
- Size: 5px

I found out that using tools that this is a css value of..

`box-shadow: 1px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);`

But how can i convert these values for use as a SVG drop shadow? Is there any algorithm or rules to follow or a tool to make this jump. The SVG values and properties are quite different fx...

```
<filter id="dropshadow">
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="4" result="blur"/>
  <feOffset in="blur" dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetBlur"/>
 <feMerge>
  <feMergeNode in="offsetBlur"/>     
  <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
  </feMerge>
 </filter>
```

Comment: Maybe https://projectparfait.adobe.com/ once it's working again.

Comment: Thats useful for css but doesnt get me the SVG values..

Answer (score 1):

Use Photoshop generator for SVG.
This is result of generating ellipse with necessary style

```
<filter filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="Filter_0" x="0px" y="0px" width="64px" height="64px"  >
  <feOffset in="SourceAlpha" dx="1.5" dy="2.598" />
  <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" stdDeviation="2.236" />
  <feFlood flood-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" result="floodOut" />
  <feComposite operator="atop" in="floodOut" in2="blurOut" />
  <feComponentTransfer><feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.15"/></feComponentTransfer>
  <feMerge>
    <feMergeNode/>
    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
  </feMerge>
</filter>
```

[How to generate SVG images in Photoshop](http://creativedroplets.com/generate-svg-with-photoshop-cc-beta/)